# Как удалить все классы у найденных элементов?

Tags: javascript

Есть html код, необходимо чтобы js удалял у всех найденных элементов определенный класс.

```js
var st = document.getElementById('st');
st.classList.remove('st');
```

```css
.st {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div id="st" class="st">1</div>
</div>
<div class="block">
  <div id="st" class="st">2</div>
</div>
<div class="block">
  <div id="st" class="st">3</div>
</div>
```

Необходимо, чтобы класс удалился у всех элементов. Желательно сделать так, чтобы код был автономным и удалял класс если элементов  станет 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var st = document.querySelectorAll('[id="st"]');
for (var i = 0; i < st.length; i++) {
  st[i].classList.remove('st');
}
```

```css
.st {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div id="st" class="st">1</div>
</div>
<div class="block">
  <div id="st" class="st">2</div>
</div>
<div class="block">
  <div id="st" class="st">3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Когда у элемента есть атрибут id, это значит, что на странице будет только один элемент с таким id. А метод `document.getElementById('');` всегда возвращает только один элемент.

Для выборки нескольких элементов обычно используют метод `document.querySelectorAll('');`.

Как только выбрали все элементы, можно пройтись по ним циклом, и с помощью метода `el.classList.remove('');` удалить нужный класс.

Answer (score 0):

```
    if($('.st').length==5) {
       $('.block').each(function(){
         $(this).children().removeClass('st');
       });
    }
```